# Can't play streaming audio in Android web browser

Tags: android, html, streaming, audio-streaming, html5-audio

Ok, I am lost. I have 2 different streams and can use either one. But neither will work on a webpage PHP or HTML on Android. I've tried using the AUDIO tag for HTML5 and some other Javascript libs. A search of this board hasn't helped me much. Just dead ends.

The Mp3 stream is http://8713.live.streamtheworld.com:80/WWWQFMMOB_SC

The AAC stream is http://5913.live.streamtheworld.com:80/WWWQFMAAC_SC

These are actually inside of .pls files (playerservices.streamtheworld.com/pls/WWWQFM.pls) (MP3 Stream) (playerservices.streamtheworld.com/pls/WWWQFMAAC.pls) (AAC).
I can use any of them on an iPhone, but Android...no luck. It doesn't have to be in the same code as the iPhone player.

Any ideas?? I'm not a pro at code by far, but I'm not bad at adapting, changing and following the logic. Thanks!!

Comment: Which version of Android have you tried it on?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried?  If you can't get it working, I run a service that supports the native players in Android.  http://audiopump.co/preview.php

Comment: @Brad Here's what I have...

Comment: @Brad Here's what I have... I've tried it on several versions of Android. Not exactly sure since I'm an iOS guy. But borrowed phones from around the office and it doesn't work on any of them.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Radio Stations</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="player2" width="290" src="http://8713.live.streamtheworld.com:443/WWWQFM_SC" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls" autoplay="true"></audio>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Your clients may not support it.  Try opening a test page on them to see what support for what codecs there is:  http://html5test.com/